# Cannot add Xamarin.Facebook.AudienceNetwork.Android package

Tags: android, facebook, xamarin, facebook-audience-network

Project builds in DEBUG but cannot build in RELEASE without AudienceNetwork package.

Adding Xamarin.Facebook.AudienceNetwork.Android...

Attempting to resolve dependency 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v4 (= 23.4.0)'.

Updating 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v4 23.4.0.1' to 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v4 23.4.0' failed.

Unable to find versions of 'Xamarin.Facebook.Android, Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat, Xamarin.Android.Support.Vector.Drawable, Xamarin.Android.Support.Animated.Vector.Drawable' that are compatible with 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v4 23.4.0'.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to take a gander at the dependencies of the packages you're trying to install. For example with the NuGet package you're trying to install:

Xamarin.Facebook.AudienceNetwork.Android (https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Facebook.AudienceNetwork.Android/)

It has dependencies on the following packages:

- Xamarin.Facebook.Android (>= 4.13.0)
- Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat (>= 23.3.0)
- Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.RecyclerView (>= 23.3.0)
- Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Ads (>= 29.0.0.2)

Now the error regarding your `Xamarin.Android.Support.v4` package trying to downgrade from 23.4.0.1 -> 23.4.0 is basically saying that there are no packages that will work with this version.

- `Xamarin.Android.Support.Vector.Drawable`
- `Xamarin.Android.Support.Animated.Vector.Drawable`

The reason behind this is that the NuGet dependency for both these items:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Android.Support.Vector.Drawable/
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Android.Support.Animated.Vector.Drawable/

Both have a dependency on `Xamarin.Android.Support.v4` 23.4.0.1. Thus it cannot downgrade properly. You will most likely need to uninstall your support packages and reinstall just the package that you want to install to ensure a proper dependency graph.

Comment: I had all of the dependencies for Xamarin.Facebook.AudienceNetwork.Android. I got it to work by downgrading Xamarin.Facebook by one version (the older version is not dependent on that specific version of Support v4). Thanks.